# Error observed when trying to list gcp buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to list buckets inside my gcp-project using the command

`gcloud alpha storage ls`

but i am gettingthe below error
`ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`

The gsutil command works without any issue `gsutil ls`

I did check the command option and am i able to view the below

```
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.storage) Command name argument expected.

Available groups for gcloud alpha storage:

Available commands for gcloud alpha storage:

      cp                      *(ALPHA)*  Upload, download, and copy Cloud
                              Storage objects.
      ls                      *(ALPHA)*  List Cloud Storage buckets and objects.
      rm                      *(ALPHA)*  Delete objects and buckets.
```

I am checking this from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/storage/ls

few other commands with the error output are as below
`gcloud alpha storage ls --project=<project-name>`

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: I did find a work-around using below gsutil command

```for a in project-1 project-2;  do gsutil ls -p $a; done```

Not sure why gcloud command is giving the error

Comment: If you are certain that you are on the latest gcloud, with the latest alpha components and using a supported python version (3.5-3.8) then it would probably make sense to file a bug report on their tracker. I personally would just use gsutil until the storage component is in GA (if ever).

Comment: Could you post the workaround that you found as an answer to help users facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @George, he was able to overcome the error he got with the following command:

`for a in project-1 project-2;  do gsutil ls -p $a; done`

As mentioned by @somethingsomething, make sure you are on the latest version of gcloud, with the latest alpha components and using a supported python version (3.5-3.8), then is recommended to file a bug report with the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list)